# Marker Plotted in Wrong Position

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

My DataTable:

```
Country                        Types of sales   Total sales($)  Name                                State       
United states of America           chemicals    12662871    Obama                                GA 
United states of America           electronics  20145684    Romney                               ON 
United states of America           textiles     22458756    Gliton                               MB 
United states of America           automobiles  34235684    Andrew Jackson                       BC 
United states of America           chemicals    19438333    James Madison                       AB
```

Instead of Giving the state Column, if I give the name Column the name also plotted in the geochart map like in the attachment file.

This is only occurred if the displayMode is Marker.

Javascript code:

```
<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Google Visualization API Sample</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function drawMarkersMap() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

        ['Name', 'Total Sales'],
        ['Romney', 20145684],
        ['Obama', 12662871],
        ['Gliton', 22458756],
        ['Andrew Jackson', 34235684],
        ['James Madison', 19438333]
    ]);

        var options = {

            region: 'US',
            resolution: 'provinces',
            displayMode:'markers',
            width: 400,
            height: 400,
            colorAxis: {
                //values: [-1, 0, 1],
                colors: ['#FF0000']
            }
        };

        var geochart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));

        geochart.draw(data, options);

        google.visualization.events.addListener(geochart, 'select', function (eventOption) {

            var item = geochart.getSelection();


            var value = data.getValue(item[0].row, 1);

            alert(value);
        });
    }

    google.load('visualization', '1', { packages: ['geochart'] });

    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMarkersMap);


</script>

</head>

<body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">

<div id="visualization"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

please kindly provide the solution to resolve it.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I really don't understand what you're trying to do here. Your example code doesn't include locations to the geochart. Can you change your example such that it shows positions (in addition to the sales volume)?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display each person as in charge of a state, with their name displayed on hover like this:

[image: Geochart Sample]

You can achieve that using code like this, using `{v:'value',f:'format'}` notation:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string','Name');
  data.addColumn('number','Sales');
  data.addRows([
    [{v:'MA',f:'Romney'}, 20145684],
    [{v:'IL',f:'Obama'}, 12662871],
    [{v:'NH',f:'Gliton'}, 22458756],
    [{v:'TN',f:'Andrew Jackson'}, 34235684],
    [{v:'VA',f:'James Madison'}, 19438333]
  ]);

  var options = {
    region: 'US',
    resolution: 'provinces',
    width: 600,
    height: 400
  };
```

var chart = new google.visualization.GeoChart(document.getElementById('visualization'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
};